# How to split one list in a list of x list with python?

Tags: python

How to split a list in a list of x lists in python ?

Exemple with list splited in 2 lists:

```
elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
-> ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Exemple with list splited in 3 lists (note the third list of tuple, containing "division rest"):

```
elements = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
-> ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9])
```

etc ...

Comment: Or, read the `grouper` recipe on [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html).

Comment: are you trying to split the original list into a tuple of lists or a list of lists? your examples show a tuple but the question is a little unclear

Comment: the module `more_itertools` has `more_itertools.divide(n, iterable)`, which splits the the elements from iterable into n parts, maintaining order. One difference to the requirements from the question is that the remainder/s are added to the first 'sublists'. Second could be that it returns a list of generators. So do the following to get a list of lists `children = divide(3, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])` followed `list(c) for c in children]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try like this:

EDIT2:-

```
i,j,x=len(seq),0,[]

for k in range(m):

    a, j = j, j + (i+k)//m

    x.append(seq[a:j])

return x
```

Call like

```
seq = range(11), m=3
```

**Result**

```
result : [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

---

---

```
def chunks(l, n):
    return [l[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
```

EDIT1:-

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> zip(*[iter(x)]*3)
[(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
```

Comment: Thank's, see the edited answer. But for EDIT2 'j' variable disapoint me: NameError: name 'j' is not defined

Comment: @bux:- Sorry that was a typo! Updated that :)

Comment: You get it! Thank's !

Answer (score 1):

```
def chunk(iterable ,n):
    le = len(iterable)
    if n > le:
        return  iterable
    mo = le % n # get mod from length of the iterable % required len sublists 
    diff = le - mo #  if there was any mod, i.e 10 % 3 = 1, diff will be 9
    sli = le / n
    res = [iterable[ind:ind + sli] for ind in range(0, diff, sli)]
    res[-1] = res[-1] + iterable[diff:] # add from diff to end of the last sublist
    return tuple(res) # return a tuple lists
```

If `mo = le % n == 0`  diff will be equal to the length of the list so `iterable[diff:]` will add nothing.

Comment: Hi, Sorry, with this case: chunk([0,1,2,3], 2) , result:
([0, 1, 2],)

Comment: yep noticed it just there myself, give me a min, left hardcoded value in by mistake

Comment: Thank's ^^ But, another problem :D >>> chunk([0,1,2,3,4,5], 2) ; result:
([0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]) instead ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5])

Comment: that is correct, three sublists of two elements

Comment: My question is to get: x sublist, not y sublist with x elements :)

Comment: easy fix, just had to change a line

Comment: not yet: chunk([0,1,2,3,4,5], 2) ;result: ([0], [3])

Comment: forgot to remove a /n

Comment: Yep, it's working now. 1 point added. Thank's

Comment: no worries, you're welcome, your question should not have been marked as a dup as the answers don't address your uestion